# JavaScript update

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone told me that I need to replace these two codes

> js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js
>
> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'

for a newer version, do I need to update two or one is universal for all the functions?
Which version should I download and also will that affect a jquery functions I have?

Comment: These are pretty self explanatory...

Comment: Which lines are 44 and 57? Please mark them in your script.

Comment: @Dalia: In the future, please take some time to properly format your question. There's no need to use all caps.

Comment: The code you've given looks perfectly ok. Can you give a bit more code?

Comment: I just put the entire code ,example one and two.two is the one making the problem > $magicLineTwo

Comment: I have created this jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghAkB/ You can modify it, and save it, then share the new link with us. It will make this easier.

Comment: It was missing #example-two. Did I do this right? http://jsfiddle.net/ghAkB/9/

Comment: I can't pin down this issue, sorry. Best of luck.

Comment: Just before the last "function", seems like you're missing `;`: `$magicLineTwo.stop().animate({ /* ... */ })` <-- here.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
position.left
```

Instead of

```
position().left
```

Also, looks like your missing some semi colons at the end of a few of your lines;

Comment: Can you explain why? position() is a Jquery method.